# Microsoft HPC Pack API: Setting "Prefer Nodes With" programmatically

Tags: c#, hpc

You can do this via the UI:
[image]

How do I do it via the HPC API? I can't find any properties on the ISchedulerJob which apply.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property should be used:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.hpc.scheduler.ischedulerjob.orderby?view=hpc-sdk-5.1.6115#microsoft-hpc-scheduler-ischedulerjob-orderby

Values that ISchedulerJob.OrderBy accepts are:

- "Memory" ("More Memory" value in HPC UI drop-down)
- "-Memory" ("Less Memory" value in HPC UI drop-down)
- "Cores" ("More Cores" value in HPC UI drop-down)
- "-Cores" ("Fewer Cores" value in HPC UI drop-down)
- "#0", "#1", etc.

OR

their combination separated by comma, like "-Memory,-Cores"